# Passing arguments between cocoa apps

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I need to pass the values between 2 cocoa application.I have explored 2 ways -

1. Using NSDistributionNotification Center as in the below -
   [how to pass parameters between cocoa applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858112/how-to-pass-parameters-between-cocoa-applications)

Problem here is this is does not seems to work in sandboxed scenario.

2. Using MDAdditions class as in 
   [Pass arguments between Objective-C applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601744/pass-arguments-between-objective-c-applications)

Not sure, If this works in sandbox scenario. Problem here is I am not able to get changed arguments when it is reopen from dock scenario. It shows initial argument passed.Every time app2 is called/invoked from app1, different arguments will be passed. First time when app2 is opened, I am getting param. But when I hide/minimize app2 and it becomes active again (when app2 is called again from app1), it is not getting new argument. I need the param in applicationDidBecomeActive:.

Any solution for the above case?

Comment: dist notifs dont work in sandbox mode for sure

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [distributed objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/distrobjects/DistrObjects.html)

Comment: not in a sandboxed env I think. Im not 100% sure though

Answer (score 0):

the recommended way is to use XPC to pass arguments from one app to another as I get it

that works in sandbox mode too

Comment: but XPC is async and you cant guarantee the param is available when you need it to be